# DigitalOceanで運営しているWordPressサイトのキャッシュ設定方法

Tags: wordpress, mod-cache

DigitalOceanのワンクリックインストールでWordPresサイトを運営しております。
設定の手順は以下の記事のとおりです。

【初心者向け】DigitalOceanにWordPressをインストールする方法 http://manablog.org/digitalocean-how-to-install-wordpress/

GoogleのPageSpeed Insightsを利用したところ、ページのキャッシュ設定をするように注意を受けたため、.htaccessファイルに以下を記述しました。

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 15 days”
ExpiresByType image/gif “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType image/jpg “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType image/jpeg “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType image/png “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access plus 10 days”
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType text/js “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType text/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash “access plus 1 month”
</ifModule>
```

しかし、デベロッパーツールでキャッシュされているか確認しても、正常にキャッシュされておりません。表示内容は次のとおりです。

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

Googleで検索してみたところ、Apacheの設定がいるという記述があったのですが、サーバーサイドに詳しくないため、解決策がわからない状況です。

DigitalOceanで運営しているWordPressサイトのキャッシュ設定に詳しい方がおりましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。